# Set range for values for graph axes using DynamicDataDisplay

Tags: c#, wpf, graph, dynamic-data-display

I am creating a application where in I want to plot a graph with DateTime as X-axis and numbers from 0-100 as Y-axis.

I have used the following code

```
     <d3:ChartPlotter.HorizontalAxis>
        <d3:HorizontalDateTimeAxis Name="dateAxis"/>
     </d3:ChartPlotter.HorizontalAxis>
     <d3:ChartPlotter.VerticalAxis>
        <d3:VerticalIntegerAxis Name="countAxis"  />   
     </d3:ChartPlotter.VerticalAxis>


     <d3:Header FontFamily="Times New Roman" Foreground="SteelBlue"  Content="Radiation Monitoring System"/>
     <d3:VerticalAxis FontFamily="Times New Roman" Foreground="SteelBlue" Content="Radiation Number" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="346" Width="179" />
     <d3:HorizontalAxis FontFamily="Times New Roman" Foreground="SteelBlue" Content="Real time" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

  </d3:ChartPlotter>
```

How am I suppose to set the Y-axisvalues between 0 - 100 ?

Also I need to set the content of Y-axis as we see in the normal graphs.(rotated 270 degrees)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of your second requirement(rotation), but to limit your y axis values, you can use the ViewPort.Domain. Domain sets the bounds for your plotter. Example :

```
var axis = (DateTimeAxis)productPlot.MainHorizontalAxis;
double yMin = 0;
double yMax = 100;       
Rect domainRect = new Rect(xMin, yMin, xMax - xMin, yMax - yMin);
//xMin and xMax are left to your discretion based on your DateTimeAxis

plotter.ViewPort.Domain = domainRect;
```

If you could explain your second requirement more, I will try my best to update my answer with what is required.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, your answer seems to work fine. The second requirement is no longer required. Thanks a TON!!